# How can I word a life estate for myself without saying Life Estate?

Tags: mortgage, trusts, private-lending, disability, investment-trusts

I'm disabled and considering structuring a mortgage assumption to buy a primary home in Texas. My strategy is to have the seller settle a living estate trust that will bi pass me and convey to my heirs at maturity (death of the settler or note payoff). Using a Close held C corp (I'm CEO with rights to convert all holdings to instant private trust reserved) and a secondary Private Club status (I'm President with full control and 51% deciding vote) to operate a Tenement building. (Room Rentals) Using a Shareholder Agreement to define the settler and buyer rules, rights, rents, abilities and responsibilities of; the Club, trustee's, and beneficiaries. Having the settler assign me a Life Estate could trigger an acceleration by violating the terms of the original trust agreement against adding a name to title or assigning a right to a third party without permission. How can I have a life estate for myself, with rights to reside and rents defined in the grant without saying, Life Estate. Can we use, Right to reside of occupy to accomplish the same goal without using a legally defined word which will have the same effect? Is it the Effect that will trigger an acceleration or just the legal definition as outlined in the original note specifically, I need to avoid?

Comment: What is the reason for the complex structure?

Comment: This is more a question about law than about personal finance and should be migrated to Law.se

Comment: I share the question about what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to qualify for Medicaid nursing home benefits? Are you trying to defeat a creditor> Do you have a tax motivation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that I had posted my question to a finance topic. Excuse me, to answer the question about why so complicated, with the answer for the other questions, Yes. I was hoping that by explaining my strategy as simply and clearly as I could, my intentions would be understood and question answered. This strategy will allow me to separate the profits and tax obligations that come with the rents collected from myself and the settle heir beneficiary by means of shareholder agreement means no tax obligation to me. Never owning yet conveying to trust at maturity, no profit.

Comment: With right to live, I can claim the debt payment without claiming a profit or purchase that's taxable until or unless the rights vested in the remainder man account are by design of instrument instructed to do; Upon death, payment of lien in full, or bankruptcy by non settler (abandoned, executed partitioned in kind, sole signer of note)..... Property is conveyed to my heirs trust. As the right to inherit will follow the title by vestment I hold, and second tittle creation as cause of bankruptcy will be unenforceable at best an constructed as contractual an not inheritable. just a gues   .